# How to fix a special character in XSLT

Tags: xslt, special-characters

I am dealing with below XML where I need to remove a special character in firstname. é in (Andrés) not sure what is this character is actually called.  If I process firstname as is it's failing in the Vendor system

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<reportentry>
<reportdata>
    <id>12345</id>
    <firstname>Andrés</firstname>
    <lastname>Williams</lastname>
</reportdata>
</reportentry>
```

I simply tried replace function which is working, below is the code. Not sure is there any better way to deal with it ? any suggestions ?

```
 <xsl:value-of select="replace($string1, 'é', 'e')"/>
```

Full code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

<xsl:variable name="string1" select="/reportentry/reportdata/firstname"/>
<xsl:variable name="comma" select="','"/>
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/reportentry">

    <xsl:value-of select="reportdata/id"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$comma"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="replace($string1, 'é', 'e')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$comma"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="reportdata/lastname"/>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I expected result as 12345,Andres,Williams

Comment: @Venkata Penumasta - Can you say exactly what is happening for you if it is not working? Are you getting an error, for example? Also, does your XML really only have one `reportdata` entry in it, or multiple ones? Thanks!

Comment: @TimC  Hi Tim, Thanks for your replay.I am having multiple reportdata elements I am using for loop to read them. I just used one reportdata  as example as it's failing. Actual thing I want's to know is , Is there any other way to deal with this.. like in replace function I just hard coded é with e which is giving expected result. However If I see multiple letters with this type of problem instead of hard coding is there any function to deal with these ?

Comment: It's known as an [Diacritic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic). In this particular case, it is an [Acute Accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_accent) and there is nothing really "special" about it. Really, your vendor system needs to be changed or upgraded if it can't handle them. In the short term, if there is only a small set of characters you could use `translate`. For example `translate($string1, 'éó', 'eo')`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can strip most diacritics by using [`normalize-unicode()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-normalize-unicode) to convert the string to decomposed normal form (NFD), and then using `replace()` to remove all "non-spacing mark" characters (category `Mn`).

So `replace(normalize-unicode(xxx, 'NFD'), '\p{Mn}', '')`

Not tested.

But it would be better to modernise the receiving application so it can handle international names...

Comment: I was just about to post a similar answer - but I used `IsCombining_Diacritical_Marks` as the class to remove.