# How to preform two fuctions in a single XPath expression?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Is it possible to combine these two expressions to a single expression so it would select the substring before and translate the output string?

```
translate(//LogEvents/LogEvent[@StatusCode=2][1]//Asset/@Title, 'üäöõÜÄÖÕ', 'uaooUAOO')

substring-before(//LogEvents/LogEvent[@StatusCode=2][1]//Asset/@Title, '[')
```

I'm using this for our radio playout system's now playing export to make this readable for RDS and eliminate version info etc.

Comment: With XPath questions, please say which version of XPath you are using, since newer versions (2.0 and 3.1) open up many possibilities that were not available with XPath 1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
substring-before(translate(//LogEvents/LogEvent[@StatusCode=2][1]//Asset/@Title, 'üäöõÜÄÖÕ', 'uaooUAOO'), '[')
```

In XPath 3.1, you can use the arrow operator which makes this more readable:

```
//LogEvents/LogEvent[@StatusCode=2][1]//Asset/@Title => 
  translate('üäöõÜÄÖÕ', 'uaooUAOO') =>
  substring-before('[')
```

Comment: In versions higher than 1.0 there is also a better way to remove diacritics: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56992126/3016153